# SQL Server Audit Clutters Error log

Tags: sql-server, audit, error-log

I have a Server level Audit running and informational messages are continuously placed in the SQL Error log (every hour):

Audit: Server Audit: 65976, Initialized and Assigned State: STARTED
Audit: Server Audit: 65976, Initialized and Assigned State: START_FAILED
Audit: Server Audit: 65975 Session has been closed
Audit: Server Audit: 65975, State changed from: STARTED to: SHUTTING_DOWN

My question is, why does this happen and more important can this be prevented (while continuing the audit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't clutter. You need to figure out why the audit is failing, and resolve it.